# Subquery - list those that never have

Tags: oracle, subquery

I am trying to provide a listing of instructors who have never taught a course section.

first I select the listing of instructors who taught a course section

```
SELECT w.COURSE_NO
FROM INSTRUCTOR z , SECTION w
WHERE z.INSTRUCTOR_ID = w.INSTRUCTOR_ID
```

but when provide a listing who never taught it gives me no rows or an error

```
SELECT SALUTATION, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME,ZIP
FROM INSTRUCTOR,SECTION
WHERE COURSE_NO NOT IN
(SELECT w.COURSE_NO
FROM INSTRUCTOR z , SECTION w
WHERE z.INSTRUCTOR_ID = w.INSTRUCTOR_ID)
ORDER BY SALUTATION, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME,ZIP;
```

how could I provide a listing of instructors who have never taught ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you forgot to put your join predicate in the principal query :

```
SELECT SALUTATION, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME,ZIP
FROM INSTRUCTOR a,SECTION b 
WHERE a.INSTRUCTOR_ID = b.INSTRUCTOR_ID AND COURSE_NO NOT IN
    (SELECT w.COURSE_NO
    FROM INSTRUCTOR z , SECTION w
    WHERE z.INSTRUCTOR_ID = w.INSTRUCTOR_ID)
ORDER BY SALUTATION, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME,ZIP;
```

Try to use ANSI-92.

```
SELECT SALUTATION, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME,ZIP
FROM INSTRUCTOR a
INNER JOIN SECTION b ON a.INSTRUCTOR_ID = b.INSTRUCTOR_ID
WHERE COURSE_NO NOT IN
    (SELECT w.COURSE_NO
    FROM INSTRUCTOR z
    INNER JOIN SECTION w ON z.INSTRUCTOR_ID = w.INSTRUCTOR_ID
    ) 
ORDER BY SALUTATION, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME,ZIP;
```

Comment: I still get now rows , not sure why. I'll play around with it. It does look much better now.Thank you!